# Error 35600 "index out of bounds" en excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Soy nuevo en el foro, y estoy algo desesperado por ayuda.
La situación es la siguiente:

En Excel, hice un formulario ("RegPMA") que está compuesto de 1 ListView, y 1 CommandButton (Editar).

La idea es que cuando el usuario haga click en "Editar", otro formulario ("RegContaminantes") se muestre.

RegContaminantes está compuesto de 5 TextBox, 1 ComboBox y 1CommandButton ("Guardar"). Cuando el usuario haga click en "Guardar", los datos de los 5 TextBox y el ComboBox deben ser guardados en 3 hojas diferentes.

La macro esta configurada de la siguiente manera: Se hace click en Guardar, y se los valores son inscritos en la Hoja "Parámetros", descarga el formulario RegContaminantes, haciendo que RegPMA vuelva a tener el foco, sin embargo ya con los nuevos datos.

También, realiza el guardado en una segunda hoja "Datos", en la que guarda todos los datos en una sola Fila. Finalmente, necesito que los datos se guarden en una tercera hoja "PMA", con la diferencia, de que en esta hoja, necesito que cada dato se guarde en una nueva fila.

Sin embargo, en el proceso de guardado de la tercera hoja tengo un problema: `Error 35600 "Index out of Bounds"`.  En esta parte del codigo se encuentra el error: (Al depurar, resalta la primera línea del código después de `NuevaFila2`)

```
Sub DobleGuardadoContaminantes()
Dim NuevaFila2
Dim Rango As Range
Dim i As Integer
Set Rango = Sheets("PMA").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
For i = 0 To RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Count - 1
    
    NuevaFila2 = Rango.Rows.Count + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 10).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 11).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(1)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 12).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 13).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(3)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 14).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(4)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Range(NuevaFila2, 15).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(5)
    
    Next i
```

Cabe aclarar, que todo lo descrito se encuentra en la misma macro. Es una macro la que realiza el proceso de guardado de los valores en "Parámetros", "Datos" y el ListView, y otra macro la que debería realizar el guardado en la tercera hoja.

Antes de que el código quede de la forma en la que copié la linea de NuevaFila2, estaba fuera del bucle, y sólo guardaba el último item del ListView. En otro blog me recomendaron que la ponga dentro el bucle, y ahora no guarda ni el último item, ni nada. ¡Ayuda por favor!

Comment: En ningún momento das valor a `Rango` debes hacer un `Set Rango = ....` para poder utilizar su propiedad `.Rows.Count`. Por otro lado, define `i` como tipo `Long` los excels actuales tienen varias veces más filas que el máximo que puede manejar un `integer`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Damian, y mil disculpas, si definí `Rango`, pero no lo puse en el post original por error. Sucede que el código es mucho más largo, y con muchos más formularios, así que sólo copié las partes pertinentes (el resto no me genera error). Ahora editaré el post para que esa parte también este incluida. También intenté definiendo a `i` como `Long`, pero sigue saliendo error 35600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juraría que el índice mínimo en un ListView es 1.

Estás definiendo `i` como 0, así que al hacer `RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i)` estás llamando al item 0, que no existe.

Prueba así:

`For i = 1 To RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Count`

Comment: Bueno, eso sin duda soluciona el error 35600, muchísimas gracias. Con razón lo tomaba como fuera de límite. Ahora tengo otro problema: Sólo guarda el último ítem. Tratando de evitarlo es que llegué al 35600. ¿Algún consejo más, por favor?

Comment: En afán de evitar que alguien más se choque con esto:

`NuevaFila2 = Rango.Rows.Count
For i = 0 To RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Count - 1
       NuevaFila2=NuevaFila2 + 1
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PMA").Cells(NuevaFila2, 10).Value = RegPMA.ListView1.ListItems.Item(i)` (y el resto como está en el post, con las aclaraciones realizadas y con `Cells` en lugar de `Range`).
Esa es la solución. ¡Gracias a todos!

Comment: @Magno si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor, márcala como correcta: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)